# Show/Hide Multiple Select Menus

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to create a questionaire which will start with one select menu on the page, when the user chooses an option the next dropdown will appear dependant on the choice. There could be up to 10 questions in total, I'm just looking to for someone to point me to a tutorial that could help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out one of the following jQuery Plugins for dependent/chained selects:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/related-selects
- http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects
- https://code.google.com/p/jqueryselectcombo/

Here are a couple of tutorials without plugins:

- http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/
- http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty good: http://jsatt.blogspot.com/2010/01/cascading-select-boxes-using-jquery.html. Now all you have to modify is when to hide/show the select menu.